# php htmlentities on a variable

Tags: php

this prints out nothing

```
print htmlentities($variable);
```

this prints out my text string that is a field from mysql that is a mediumtext. The field is 65MB

```
print $variable;
```

The question is: does htmlentities have a problem with the size of the variable or is there an obvious way (that I am missing) to debug this ?

Comment: So – what's your *question?* ...

Comment: good point will edit to post a question

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag, because the question has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: Is there any code failure or error reported? What made you ask if you need to debug anything? It would help people to answer your question if you describe what happened.

Comment: there are no errors, simply the same variable that can be printed does not print when run under the htmlentities() function. OK, adding print htmlentities($variable,ENT_IGNORE); allows it to print, so this was not size but something in the string :(

Answer (score 1):

Silly enough this is the first time I had this come up and failed to read the manual :( 
The fix was to:

```
print htmlentities($variable,ENT_SUBSTITUTE);
```

my first attempt to use ENT_IGNORE allowed the string to print but may have security implications https://www.php.net/htmlentities

I apologize that I assumed this was a variable size issue, as all the other few hundred results would print, this made me think this was the only result that did not print just after enlarging the field in mysql, then all of a sudden this started happening. Instead the last bit of data I added to the field had a copyright non ascii character :( sigh